# Expected value and General distribution Function

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Given an iid random variable, the expected value is usually defined as follow:
$E[T]=\int_0^\infty t f(t) dt $ where $f(t)$ is the pdf of $T$.

On a book I found this definition (without any other specification or reference):
$E[T]=\int_0^\infty t dB(t)$ where B(t) is said to be the distribution function of $T$.

What is the relationship between $B(t)$ and $f(t)$ since the $E[T]$ must be the same?

Comment: What's an iid random variable?

Comment: $$B(t)=P(T\leqslant t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds\qquad dB(t)=f(t)dt$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate "What's an iid random variable?" Zen answer: The same as the sound of one hand clapping.